Showing that the canonical bundle of $\Bbb CP^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$.
I'm trying to show that the canonical bundle for $\Bbb CP^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$ by showing that these have the same transition functions. For $\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$ we have $$g_{ij}= \left(\frac{z^i}{z^j}\right)^{-(n+1)} = \left(\frac{z^j}{z^i}\right)^{(n+1)}.$$
For $K = \bigwedge^{n,0}T^*\Bbb CP^n$ these are a bit harder to compute. If we take the standard open cover $U_i=\{[w]\mid w^i\ne0\}$ and consider charts $(U_i,z_i=(z^1_i,\dots,z^n_i))$ and $(U_j,z_j=(z^1_j,\dots,z^n_j))$ we have the transition maps for these in $U_i\cap U_j$ given by $$z^k_j = \frac{w^k}{w^j}=\frac{w^k}{w^i}\frac{w^i}{w^j} = \frac{w^i}{w^j}z^k_i.$$
Over $U_j$ we also have a local frame given by $$\omega_j=(-1)^jdz^1_j\wedge\dots \wedge \widehat{dz^j_j}\wedge \dots \wedge dz^n_j.$$ To find the transition maps $\tau_{ij}$ for the canonical bundle I have to relate $$\omega_j=\tau_{ij}\omega_i.$$
If I look at the singular terms $dz^k_i$ I get by computing these that $$dz^k_j = d\left(\frac{w^i}{w_j}z^k_i\right) =d\left(\frac{w^i}{w_j}\right)z^k_i + dz^k_i\frac{w^i}{w_j} = -\frac{(w^i)^2}{(w^j)^2}d\left(\frac{w^j}{w^i}\right) + dz^k_i\frac{w^i}{w^j} = -\frac{w^i}{w^j}\left(\frac{w^i}{w^j}d\left(\frac{w^j}{w^i}\right)-dz^k_i\right)$$
but this doesn't seem to be helpful at all. How does one go about finding these transition maps? Also, I know that this can probably be done using some exact sequences like the Euler sequence, but I'm looking to find these maps explicitly.

It is well known that the cocycles $g_{ij}$ of the canonical bundle $\omega$ of a complex manifold $X$ are given in this way. If $\psi_i\colon U_i\to \mathbb C^n$ are local charts, then
$$g_{ij}=\det J(\psi_j\circ \psi_i^{-1})(\psi_i(z)),$$
where $J$ means the Jacobian matrix of the map $\psi_j\circ \psi_i^{-1}$. Let me know if you need to prove this result.
In our specific case we have natural charts for $\mathbb P^{n}$:
$$\psi_i\colon U_i:=\{z_i\neq 0\}\to \mathbb C^{n}, \qquad (z_0, \dots, z_n)\mapsto \left(\frac{z_0}{z_i},\dots \widehat{\frac{z_i}{z_i}}, \dots, \frac{z_n}{z_i}  \right).$$
But then the transition maps are
$$ \psi_j\circ \psi_i^{-1}\colon \mathbb C^{n}\to \mathbb C^{n}, \qquad (x_0,\dots, \widehat{1}_i, \dots, x_n)\mapsto  \left(\frac{x_0}{x_j},\dots \frac{1_i}{x_j}, \dots, \widehat{\frac{x_j}{x_j}}\dots, \frac{x_n}{x_j}  \right).$$
The Jacobian matrix is then
$$J(\psi_j\circ\psi_i^{-1})=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{x_j} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0_i & 0 & \dots  & -\frac{x_0}{x_j^2} &  0 & \dots & 0 \\
\dots \dots \\
\dots \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0_i & 0 & \dots  & -\frac{1}{x_j^2} &  0 & \dots & 0 \\
\dots \dots \\
\dots \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0_i &  0 & \dots & \frac{-x_n}{x_j^2} & 0 & \dots & \frac{1}{x_j}
 \end{pmatrix}  $$
If you develop the determinant with respect the $i-$row then you get easily
$$g_{ij}=\det(J(\psi_j\circ\psi_i^{-1})=(-1)^{i+j}\frac{1}{x_j^2}\cdot \frac{1}{x_j^{i-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{x_j^{n-i}}=(-1)^{i+j}\frac{1}{x_j^{n+1}}=(-1)^{i+j}\left(\frac{z_i}{z_j}\right)^{n+1}$$
that are the cocycles of $O_{\mathbb P^n}(-n-1)$.

Thank you for the answer. Should there be a factor of $(-1)^{i+j+1}$? @federico-fallucca

What do you mean "should there be"? Remember that line bundles defined up to a multiplicative local constant gives isomorphic line bundles. In our specific case sends a point $(p, k)$ in the chart $U_i\times \mathbb C$ to $(p,(-1)^ik)$

For the issue of annoying signs, maybe this post will suggest a remedy.

Very useful, thank you very much :)
